# Full array evaluating as empty and null

Tags: php, arrays, csv, usort

I have a very strange problem that I have been unable to find an answer to. I have a PHP function that reads CSV data into an array then returns true if the data was successfully read and passes the array back by reference variable

```
function ReadCsvDataIntoArray($path, &$headers, &$array, $idFilter = NULL){     
    if(file_exists($path)){
        $fh = fopen($path, 'r');
        if($fh){
            $headers = fgetcsv($fh);
            $rowIdx = 0;
            while($row = fgetcsv($fh)){ 
                $addRow = true;
                if($idFilter != NULL){      
                    if(isset($row[0])){
                        if(!in_array($row[0], $idFilter)){
                            $addRow = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($addRow){
                    $colIdx = 0;
                    foreach($row as $val){      
                        $array[$rowIdx][$headers[$colIdx]] = $val;
                        $colIdx++;  
                    }
                    $rowIdx++;                      
                }
            }           
            fclose($fh);
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "Unable to open file: ".$path;
        }
    } else {
        echo "CSV doesn't exist: ".$path;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the function returns as true I then check to make sure the array wasn't passed back as null or empty, then sort the data.

```
if($this->ReadCsvDataIntoArray($client_library_path, $headers, $CSVdata, $log)){
     if($CSVData != NULL){

          usort($CSVdata, create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a["engagement"] < $b["engagement"];'));

      // Do stuff with the sorted array

     } else {
          echo "CSV data is NULL.\n";
     }
```

I keep getting "CSV data is NULL" from this. If I change the logic to `if($CSVData == NULL)` or even `if(empty($CSVData))` it enters the `if` statement, attempts to sort the array (which is full, even though the `if` statement says it's empty) and does stuff with the data.

This is where my second issue comes in. This usort works on my localhost:

```
usort($CSVdata, function($a, $b) { return $a["scheduled"] < $b["scheduled"]; });
```

but it doesn't work on the server because of its php version, so I have changed it to:

```
usort($CSVData, create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a["scheduled"] < $b["scheduled"];'));
```

But with the `create_function` version of the usort I get this error message

```
Warning: usort(): The argument should be an array
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the fact that my full array is somehow being evaluated as empty and null even when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

> …and passes the array back by reference variable…

And this:

> If the function returns as true I then check to make sure the array
>   wasn't passed back as null or empty, then sort the data.

Why are you doing this? If you are checking `true` or `false` then checking if it is `null` or `empty` what is the value of that? Just check if it is `null` or `empty` by doing this instead:

```
        // return true;
        return $array;
    } else {
        echo "Unable to open file: ".$path;
    }
} else {
    echo "CSV doesn't exist: ".$path;
}
// return false;
return $array;
```

And then get rid of the return by reference for `$array` in the interface:

```
function ReadCsvDataIntoArray($path, &$headers, $array, $idFilter = NULL){
```

Your `true` or `false` logic is probably broken & not worth dealing with correctly at all. But why spend time reinventing the wheel if the value returns `null` or `empty` and that is what you are acting on.

Also you can then adjust this `$CSVData` logic to fit the new structure:

```
 $CSVData = $this->ReadCsvDataIntoArray($client_library_path, $headers, $CSVdata, $log);

 if(!empty($CSVData)){

      usort($CSVdata, create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a["engagement"] < $b["engagement"];'));

  // Do stuff with the sorted array

 } else {
      echo "CSV data is empty.\n";
 }
```

Also, your whole `return true` logic is based strictly on the file itself can be opened:

```
    $fh = fopen($path, 'r');
    if($fh){
        // Code removed for structural illustration purposes.
        // ...
        // ...
        fclose($fh);
        return true;
    } else {
```

But you say this; empahsis mine:

> I have a PHP function that reads CSV data into an array then **returns
>   true if the data was successfully read**…

No. Your logic *does not check if the data was read*  successfully. Your logic simply returns `true` if *the file itself can be read*. Which does not mean the *contents* of the file itself is valid. Have you checked the file itself? Or did you check if this line:

```
while($row = fgetcsv($fh)){
```

Actually has values in `$row` by doing something like this?

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
```

I think that maybe your CSV has line formatting issues. Like it was saved on a Windows machine but is now being read on a Mac OS X or Linux machine or the other way around. Look at this in the documentation for `fgetcsv`:

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading
>   files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the
>   auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help
>   resolve the problem.

So perhaps add this line enabling `auto_detect_line_endings` to your function like this:

```
function ReadCsvDataIntoArray($path, &$headers, &$array, $idFilter = NULL){
    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```

Comment: I thought this might be the problem as well, but I still get the same results when getting the array as a return variable as you suggest.

Comment: This info is very helpful. I agree that it makes more sense to pass the array as a return variable. I also checked and the array is evaluated a `!empty` inside `ReadCsvDataIntoArray()` before being returned and `empty` after it is returned. I know the data is valid and properly structured because everything works fine when I work with the "empty" array. Your suggestions have improved my logic, but I'm still stuck with an "empty" full array...